# Is there any way to send Fabric.io Purchase Event via PHP Server?

Tags: php, google-fabric, fabric-answers

We made an mobile application and all purchases confirming after 10-45 minutes later via php server side logic.

Sample: if user clicks to buy button, getting request taken response message then server logic process some logic and confirming after this action.

So, we need to send log purchase event from php server to fabric.io server. Is there any way to do this? Or what is your opinions?

I made some searches about server to server communication and there isnt anything.

Comment: You would need to send the event back down to your app and then log the confirmed purchase event at that point.

Comment: Yes, but we can't confirm it sent successfully to fabric or user may not open the app. So i think there isnt any way to send it at this moment. We are considering making another application that handles the purchase events.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have a guarantee that the app would receive the verified event then there isn't a solution for this currently.

Answer (score 0):

this is not how `Answers` works. you could in best case let the mobile client request the order status from the web-server and then report a successful purchase or a declined transaction to `Answers` from there... or even indicate to the mobile client, that the purchase is still being processed (without logging that as an event)... when a purchase takes that long, that's almost mandatory.

just see for yourself, [Fabric for Web](https://docs.fabric.io/web/fabric/settings/notification.html) appears read-only.

Answer (score 0):

there isnt any way to send it at this moment.